# Finding the line of execution in a browser

Tags: jsp, web-applications, internet-explorer-10

I have an web application which is in production. It stops execution on IE 10 browser and the flow stops. i.e. user has no were to go, he gets a blank screen.
The issue is only with a IE10 browser. In all other browsers I dont see this issue.
Whats interesting is that this issue is only observed in the production systems. i.e. it does not replicate in my local environment. Therefore I cannot debug from the code. I can only access the online system just like any outside user.
I want to know at which line in the jsp page the execution stops. 
Are there any tools that tell me the lines in the jsp that were executed in IE?

Thanks in Advance,

Mujeeb

Comment: You do any browser detection? If so, I would remove it first and see what happens. If not, I would try some network analyzer (wireshark?) watch the packets and compare them with other browsers traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP isn't executed by the browser. It is handled by the server, and HTML + script markup is sent to the browser. The server may modify the markup which gets sent based on the User Agent.

Do you have a debugging plugin for IE 10 preview? Try pressing F12 to open the debugger. If that doesn't work, just right-click and View Source, to see how much of the markup, if any, was sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks GuthMD. The F12 script debugger was just what I needed.